# Info: JSP gets error tagged in Source View on Chrome devtools

Tags: reactjs

I started with reactJS and everything looks ok. But there is a warning, that the elems of the list have no key.

Thats more or less copied from textbook:

```
 render: function() {
            const type = this.props.type;
            const key = this.props.type + this.props.id;

            // if(this.state.elem === null)
            return (
                    <li key={key}>
                    {type} leer
                    </li>
            );
    }
```

So it should work and it really does work. I see the list elems with correct type followed by 'leer'. But I got the warning about missing 'key' in an element of the list.

I checked the main.js source in the developer window (chrome) and line with  is flagged as 'Syntaxerror' unexpected token '<'.

That struck me like being an error in the toolchain. I put my first question on stackoverflow.

That was all false alarm:

The warning about the missing 'key' was the check on the first level element in the list. As  compiled to some text it was a correct warning.

The syntax error in js source was due to the source viewer not knowing about babel.

Should I delete this info? Would've helped a bit.

Comment: are you sure `type` and `id` are in `props`?  I would open up the browser dev tools and put a breakpoint on the `return` line and see what values `type` and `key` are

Comment: Usually you define the `key` prop inside the loop at `<ul>` level